# Inserting a Content Note

Tags: apex, dml, contentnote

The `ContentNote` represents a Note in Salesforce so I'm trying to insert one into a specific opportunity but I don't understand how to specify the right opportunity id.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-
us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm

Edit 3: Figured out why it wasn't working. Need to insert the `ContentNote` first and then insert the `ContentDocumentLink`

```
ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
cn.Title = 'test1';
String body = 'Please work';
cn.Content = Blob.valueOf(body.escapeHTML4());
insert cn;

ContentDocumentLink link2 = new ContentDocumentLink();
link2.ContentDocumentId = cn.id;
link2.LinkedEntityId = 'Id of my opportunity';
link2.ShareType = 'C';
link2.Visibility = 'AllUsers';

insert(link2);
```

From what the person suggested below me...I changed my code. This is executing but nothing is being added to the opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a ContentDocumentLink record in addition to the ContentNote.

```
       ContentDocumentLink newCD = new ContentDocumentLink();
        newCD.ContentDocumentId = document.id;
        newCD.LinkedEntityId = sObject.id;
        newCD.ShareType = 'V';
        newCD.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
```

If you want the Note to be visible to all Users, use the following:

```
        ContentDocumentLink link2 = new ContentDocumentLink();
        link2.ContentDocumentId = document.id;
        link2.LinkedEntityId = userInfo.getOrganizationId();
        link2.ShareType = 'C';
        link2.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
```

Comment: The `ContentDocumentId` is referring to the `ContentNote`, right?

Comment: Yes, cn.id in your example.

Comment: How would I be able to specify the opportunity I wish to insert this in?

Comment: Which Opportunity are you wanting to assign it to? Are you writing a trigger or working in the Exec Anonymous window?

Comment: Right now, I'm working on the exec anonymous window so I want to assign it to a specific opportunity once I create the `ContentNote` object. There has to be a way to do this

Comment: And also, edited my post

Comment: You have to query for your Opportunity. If you're just in Ex Anon then you could do: link2.LinkedEntityId = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE ID = 'yourOppId'  LIMIT 1].id